# enderland's two week notice

Tags: discussion

Well, this is probably the most difficult post to write I've ever written on this site. I have been part of this community more than six years at this point (including 4+ as a moderator) but circumstances in my life mean that it is time for me to take a step back and resign from being a moderator.

Realistically there are many reasons contributing to this, not the least of which just turned a month old in the enderland household.

I am **immensely** proud of the site that The Workplace has become. Many of you are too workplace-young to remember the early days and overwhelming skepticism most other SE users had regarding our site success. This site succeeded in spite of a lot of long odds. From the early beta all those years ago to now, it's been a wild ride, filled with adventure.

This site will continue to help users - not just those answering questions but the *millions* of people who are "reached" by questions and answers every day. We consistently have 40k-50k page visits every workday (suspiciously, less on Friday and much less on the weekends..) which means many real people are having their lives changed for the better by the Workplace.

Folks, it has been an honor to serve as a moderator here.

Comment: so in a few years can we expect enderland2 to apply for mod?

Comment: I think you need to be at least 14 years old to use SE @SaggingRufus ;)

Comment: So 14 years *marks calendar*

Comment: @SaggingRufus even worse, you need to be 18 to be capable of signing legally binding agreements like the mod agreement. We'll all need to do our part to keep the place nice and tidy while waiting for enderland2 :)

Comment: @mbrig Being underage doesn't give you the right to shout at SE for kicking you off the mod team for violating the agreement, if you did violate it...

Comment: @mbrig You're allowed to sign them; it's just that you're allowed an instant, condition-free exit clause but they're not.

Answer (score 26):

> there are many reasons contributing to this, not the least of which
>   just turned a month old in the enderland household.

Sounds like one of the best reasons of all.

Good luck in whatever you do.

Answer (score 16):

I remember the early days vividly... To call it a struggle doesn't do it justice: the toll that wrangling a community of smart, opinionated people took on the early mod teams was immense. But y'all pulled together and defied expectations - and you were an instrumental part of that, enderland.

We all owe you our thanks for sticking it out this long; not just sticking it out, but contributing and offering guidance and leadership right to the end.

So, thank you enderland - and best wishes for your future endeavors!

Comment: The recent HNQ drama made me recall the... wars of text that were written on the subject here 5+ years ago :-)

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for the years you've dedicated to making The Workplace a good and helpful site.  Best wishes for the whole enderland family.  It's been great to serve with you.

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations on the family news. Scared me for a minute I thought you were leaving, not just resigning from being a moderator.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to see you go Enderland.. but congratulations on the new family!

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for serving as our voice on the mod team.  You were a great mod and will make a great father I am sure.

Answer (score 7):

Be Well Sir.

Good luck, and Godspeed

Answer (score 7):

It's been an honour to serve with you, sir.  Enjoy your fatherhood!

Answer (score 6):

Good luck and good health to you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you have done to make this site a success and best wishes to you and your family.