# Great effort Enderland a well deserved 100k

Tags: discussion

Well done mate, you've put in a lot of solid quality effort and been a great example to all of us.

Comment: It's worth noting [enderland left](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/enderlands-two-week-notice) and hasn't been [active since last year](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland); however, still an achievement since their contributions are still being found helpful! (I'm sure you all knew this, it's just a FYI to anyone who didn't)

Comment: Someone actually cast a CLOSE vote on this.  Amazing.

Comment: @MisterPositive I just cast a VtC. "Well deserved" is obviously "primarily opinion based" :-)

Comment: @enderland Duh.  I should know that...

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations! Well done! I've always enjoyed your contributions.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks! Guess residual rep is a thing.. logged into +2100 rep just now :-)

Comment: Ah.... screenshot next time

Answer (score 8):

Always the wise one.

Thank you for your contributions.  You are the reason I didn't leave SE after a few weeks. (although some may curse you for that)

Your answers are always well reasoned and helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I extend the congratulations, even though I admit not being aware he is no longer actively among us.

Such a score reflects a lot of dedication, some of which I've personally benefited from.

So, regards, and thank you.